# Show keyboard like Whatsapp when record a video

Tags: java, android, layout, keyboard

I am looking for the better way to show the keyboard like Whastapp when I have recorded a video. I show you some pictures with what I want to get and what is my problem:

[You can see like Whatsapp has the EditText over the keyboard, but the other elements are in the same place](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Szjw.jpg)

[Before to make click in EditText in my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFNlR.jpg)

[EditText is under keyboard and like you can see, the layout in the background (a TextureView) has been moved to up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7saP2.jpg)

I am looking for a way to stay all the elementes in the same place when the keyboard is open, but the EditText that invoke the keyboard will be over it. Any idea?

Thank you.

Edit with part of my xml code:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/flMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextureView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/surface_view" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        style="@style/CardViewTheme"
        android:id="@+id/cardViewMessage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="56dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:translationZ="1dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:cardCornerRadius="20dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutMessage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txtMessage"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@null"
                android:hint="Type a message"
                android:imeOptions="actionSend"
                android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
                android:maxLines="6"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:textColorHint="#B3A8A8A8" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `windowSoftInputMode` as `adjustPan`.

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
```

> #### adjustPan
>
> The activity's main window is not resized to make room for the soft keyboard. Rather, the contents of the window are automatically panned so that the current focus is never obscured by the keyboard and users can always see what they are typing. This is generally less desirable than resizing, because the user may need to close the soft keyboard to get at and interact with obscured parts of the window.

Comment: I am using adjustPan in the screenshot, it was my first option, but it is not working fine. I have edited the question with part of my xml code.